# Convergence of the series ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{n!}{n^n\,} \cdot e^n $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does the series $\displaystyle {\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\frac{n!}{n^n\,} \cdot e^n $ converge?

I tried the **[Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)**. But because of the limit is $1$, this test does not give me any information about whether it converges or not.

Comment: The limit of the ratio may be $1$, but since the ratio  is always greater than $1$ this implies divergence

Answer (score 4):

From $e^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}$ it follows that $e^n>\frac {n^n}{n!}$ (which is one of the positive summands). Hence in your series, each summand is $>1$.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Stirling approximation: the term is asymptotic to $\sqrt{2\pi n}$, so a comparison tells us it diverges.